# Save data To iniFile in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

i have this unit that save settings to `iniFile`

```
///////////////////////////////////////
// IniSettings.pas
//
// A class for saving settings (or whatever) in an .ini file.
//
// This is made in FireMonkey, but should be usable in Delphi too.
// Example of use in the bottum of the doc.

unit IniSettings;

interface

uses Inifiles;

type
  TSettings = class(TMemIniFile)
  private
    function GetSomeData: String;
    procedure SetSomeData(const Value: String);
    function GetFormTop: Integer;
    procedure SetFormTop(const Value: Integer);
    function GetFormLeft: Integer;
    procedure SetFormLeft(const Value: Integer);
    function GetFormHeight: Integer;
    function GetFormWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetFormHeight(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetFormWidth(const Value: Integer);

  public
    procedure Save();
    property SomeData: String    read GetSomeData   write SetSomeData;
    property FormTop: Integer    read GetFormTop    write SetFormTop;
    property FormLeft: Integer   read GetFormLeft   write SetFormLeft;
    property FormWidth: Integer  read GetFormWidth  write SetFormWidth;
    property FormHeight: Integer read GetFormHeight write SetFormHeight;

  end;

var
  Settings: TSettings;

implementation

uses
  FMX.Forms, System.SysUtils;

{ TSettings }

// Save to the file
procedure TSettings.Save;
begin
  UpdateFile;
end;

// SomeData
function TSettings.GetSomeData: String;
begin
  result := ReadString('Settings', 'SomeData', 'default');
end;

procedure TSettings.SetSomeData(const Value: String);
begin
  WriteString('Settings', 'SomeData', Value);
end;

// FormTop
function TSettings.GetFormTop: Integer;
begin
  result := ReadInteger('Settings', 'FormTop', 10);
end;

procedure TSettings.SetFormTop(const Value: Integer);
begin
  WriteInteger('Settings', 'FormTop', Value);
end;

// FormLeft
function TSettings.GetFormLeft: Integer;
begin
  result := ReadInteger('Settings', 'FormLeft', 10);
end;

procedure TSettings.SetFormLeft(const Value: Integer);
begin
  WriteInteger('Settings', 'FormLeft', Value);
end;

// FormWidth
function TSettings.GetFormWidth: Integer;
begin
  result := ReadInteger('Settings', 'FormWidth', 640);
end;

procedure TSettings.SetFormWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
  WriteInteger('Settings', 'FormWidth', Value);
end;

// FormHeight
function TSettings.GetFormHeight: Integer;
begin
  result := ReadInteger('Settings', 'FormHeight', 480);
end;

procedure TSettings.SetFormHeight(const Value: Integer);
begin
  WriteInteger('Settings', 'FormHeight', Value);
end;

initialization
  // Load/Create the 'settings.ini' file in the app folder
  Settings := TSettings.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '/settings.ini');

finalization
  // Free the ini before closing
  FreeAndNil(Settings);

end.






///////////////////////////////////////
// Example
//
// Be sure to include the IniSettings in uses
//
// Put an TEdit(Edit1) and 3 TButton(btnLoad, btnSave and btnSaveFile) to the form
// The edit is for the 'SomeData' we're gonna save in the settings.
// One button for loading the settings from the MemIniFile, one for saving to MemIniFile
// and the last for saving the MemIniFile to the physical .ini file on the drive

uses
  IniSettings;

procedure TForm1.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text   := Settings.SomeData;
  Form1.Top    := Settings.FormTop;
  Form1.Left   := Settings.FormLeft;
  Form1.Width  := Settings.FormWidth;
  Form1.Height := Settings.FormHeight;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Settings.SomeData   := Edit1.Text;
  Settings.FormTop    := Form1.Top;
  Settings.FormLeft   := Form1.Left;
  Settings.FormWidth  := Form1.Width;
  Settings.FormHeight := Form1.Height;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnSaveFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Settings.Save;
end;
```

When i call `Settings.Save;` the app force closes and i cannot find the `iniFile` on the device , any idea why i cannot save the `inifile` on the device ? is `TSettings.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))` not usable on android ? also the save settings calling `UpdateFile` Procedure in  `System.IniFiles` unit is this correct way to do ?

Comment: You cannot write to your application folder on most modern OSes, and especially on mobile devices. See the functions in IOUtils, particularly those in TPath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bad practice to save settings in the same folder as application is installed on any platform, most likely this folder will be protected from writing for regular user (think 'Program files' on Windows for example).
Correct way is to use TPath.GetHomePath folder from System.IOUtils unit.
So you should use following line to create Settings object.

```
Settings := TSettings.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'YourAppSettings.ini'));
```

Comment: TPath.GetHomePath returns a folder where we can write to, but this is not the best folder for storing .ini files on every OS (even though it works). On macOS it returns the `/Users/MyUserName` folder, and I would not like to have all the application ini files in there.

Comment: @SebastianZ on UNIX it is common practice to make those files hidden ( AKA dot-files ) or put them into hidden folders (...dot-directories) ? It is not that I like that habbit, but that is how it is typically done there, no?

Comment: I have a few dot-files and folders in the home directory on OSX. But most applications use the `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/Preferences` folders. Please don't hard code those paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save a file to your apps working data directory (and you should, other than doing it on the app running directory), you should use `GetHomePath + '/settings.ini';`. For more info on [GetHomePath](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath) and [TMemIniFile](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/IniFiles_TMemIniFile.html). Best regards and hope it helps!!!

Comment: No, ParamStr(0) cannot be undefined. It's always the fully qualified path to the location of the application itself.

Comment: I see, the ParamStr(0) is the actual parameter from the Main process call/invoke. In that case, you are correct @KenWhite!!